# Regex Oracle not matching as expected

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to match and replace string like `VA123` - so two letters and 3 numbers, but this expression is not working as intended. Any idea where I am going off?

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('test VA123', '^\[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$', 'test')
FROM dual;
```

I want the output in this case to say `test test`

Comment: You need to remove the starting anchor `^`, or replace it with word boundary `\b`

Comment: Don't escape `[`.

Comment: @HaoWu Oracle does not support word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: thanks guys! this works SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('test VA123', '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$', 'test')
FROM dual;

Comment: @sarsnake That would work but it would also match `ABC123` which might not be what you require.

Comment: Ok, I only need 2 letters, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It you want white space (or start of a string) before the matched string then you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('test VA123', '(^|\s)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$', '\1test')
         AS replaced_value
FROM dual;
```

> ```
> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | :------------- |
> | test test      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6bbf9f67e20f5de18e5f199a406c2a96)*